# Eclipse Neon 4.6: "An error occurred while collecting items to be installed"

Tags: java, eclipse

```
An error occurred while collecting items to be installed
session context was:(profile=epp.package.jee, phase=org.eclipse.equinox.internal.p2.engine.phases.Collect, operand=, action=).
Unable to read repository at http://sourceforge.net/projects/jautodoc/files/updatesite/1.14.0/net.sf.jautodoc_1.14.0.jar/download.
sun.security.validator.ValidatorException: PKIX path building failed: sun.security.provider.certpath.SunCertPathBuilderException: unable to find valid certification path to requested target
Unable to read repository at http://sourceforge.net/projects/jautodoc/files/updatesite/1.14.0/net.sf.jautodoc.velocity_1.14.0.jar/download.
sun.security.validator.ValidatorException: PKIX path building failed: sun.security.provider.certpath.SunCertPathBuilderException: unable to find valid certification path to requested target
```

I just installed Neon 4.6 and tried to add jautodoc..

Answer (score 1):

It's a problem with the new Sourceforge SSL certificate and a missing root certificate in older JRE installations. See
http://magicmonster.com/kb/prg/java/ssl/pkix_path_building_failed.html
for details.

I could reproduce the error while running Eclipse with Java 8u92. It works for me with Java 8u112.

You could update your JRE or download and unzip this [keystore](http://jautodoc.sourceforge.net/cacerts.zip) from 8u112 and update your "eclipse.ini" as follows:

-vmargs
**-Djavax.net.ssl.trustStore=<your path>\cacerts

-Djavax.net.ssl.trustStorePassword=changeit**

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem, and found it could be solved by downloading the zip'd version of JAutoDoc from https://sourceforge.net/projects/jautodoc/files/latest/download and opening the archive.

Close eclipse and removed the following folder from the features folder in eclipse if it is present:

```
net.sf.jautodoc.feature_1.14.0
```

and any of the following files from the plugins folder in eclipse if they are present (some get installed during the failed install):

```
net.sf.jautodoc_1.14.0.jar
net.sf.jautodoc.velocity_1.14.0.jar
```

Now restart eclipse and verify that JAutoDoc is definitely not there, and then close eclipse again.  Now copy the files as named above from the downloaded archive back into the plugins/features folder, and start eclipse again.  JAutoDoc should now be there again